# Issue with background and relative positioning html and css

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with html and css.

Today, for the first time, I've tried to make a page with a big image for the background.

I'm using foundation framework, and I'm stuck on one thing. As we know foundation is a adaptive framework and when I re-size my browser, I've got a bug.

You can see it on my screenshot: https://imgurhd.ru/i/270a.jpg (also here you can find my css).

I need to make the text and image under menu vertically centered on any screen size.

I'm using position relative with a percent value, as you can see. So please help me to find where is the problem.

Comment: Please provide the code (in plain text, not image form) and, if possible, a jsfiddler so we can reproduce the problem ourself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wyp9ukvx/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background size to [`cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

> **Cover**
>   This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be 
>   as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or 
>   equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

```
html { 
  background: url(/*YOUR IMAGE HERE*/) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This is supported in [most recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts)